# How to change database config in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In my AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment, I need to change the database config to use a different RDS instance.

Does anyone know how to do this at the AWS (SDK) Command line ?

Answer (score 1):

I don`t believe there is a way to change to a different RDS instance using beanstalk command line client.

The way I suggest you manage your database configuration using Elastic Beanstalk is like that:

1) Do not create a database using the Elastic Beanstalk wizard. It is much better to create a separate RDS instance and then connect your Elastic Beanstalk server to it.

2) In your project, you should have a `.env` file listing all the connection parameters. IMPORTANT: This file should be listed in `.gitignore`. So while you are coding, you can switch between your dev, stage, and production environment easily.

3) In your AWS console, you should go to Beanstalk instance > Configuration > Software. Then list under `Environment properties` all the connection parameters using [RDS pre-defined parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html).

This way you will have your servers configured and be able to switch between RDS instances in your IDE while coding.